# Dynamic form select input Calculations not working properly with div

Tags: javascript, jquery

there is some select input wrapped inside div that is controlled by options and also there is data-value in those select options.
the hide and show divs are working perfectly, but there is very weird issue that is when i select first option, it shows calculation of all the select option. but when i remove all the div around of select input then it works perfectly as i want.

```js
$('body').on('change', '#visitorcount', function() {
  for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
    if (i <= $('#visitorcount').val()) {
      $('#person' + i).show();
      $('#country' + i).show();
    } else {
      $('#person' + i).hide();
      $('#country' + i).hide();
    }
  }
});
$('body').on('change', '.ct,#visitorcount', function() {
  var priceforcountry = 0;
  $('.ct').each(function(index, element) {
    if ($(element).parent().css("display") != "none") {
      priceforcountry += +$('option:selected', this).data('fee');
    }
  });
  $('#totalcost').text(priceforcountry);
  //alert(priceforcountry);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group" id="person1">
  <div class="col-sm-4 control-label">Citizenship</div>
  <div class="col-sm-8" id="person1">
    <select class="form-control ct" id="country1" name="visitor1">

      <option value="india" data-fee="20">India</option>
      <option value="usa" data-fee="25">USA</option>


    </select>
    <div class="error-message"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<select id="visitorcount" name="visitorcount">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
</select>


<div class="row visitor" id="person2" style="display: none;">
  <div class="col-md-7">
    <div class="form-horizontal">
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-4 control-label">Citizenship</div>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
          <select name="visitor[2][country]" class="form-control ct" id="country2">
            <option value="india" data-fee="20">India</option>
            <option value="usa" data-fee="25">USA</option>


          </select>

        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>




<div class="row visitor" id="person3" style="display: none;">
  <div class="col-md-7">
    <div class="form-horizontal">

      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-4 control-label" data-xtr-key="Citizenship">Citizenship</div>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
          <select name="person[3][country]" class="form-control ct" id="country3" style="display:none">
            <option value="india" data-fee="20">India</option>
            <option value="usa" data-fee="25">USA</option>

          </select>
          <div class="error-message"></div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>



<div class="row visitor" id="person4" style="display: none;">
  <div class="col-md-7">
    <div class="form-horizontal">

      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-4 control-label" data-xtr-key="Citizenship">Citizenship</div>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
          <select name="person[4][country]" class="form-control ct" id="country4" style="display:none">
            <option value="india" data-fee="20">India</option>
            <option value="usa" data-fee="25">USA</option>

          </select>
          <div class="error-message"></div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="row visitor" id="person5" style="display: none;">
  <div class="col-md-7">
    <div class="form-horizontal">

      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-4 control-label" data-xtr-key="Citizenship">Citizenship</div>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
          <select name="person[4][country]" class="form-control ct" id="country5" style="display:none">
            <option value="india" data-fee="20">India</option>
            <option value="usa" data-fee="25">USA</option>

          </select>
          <div class="error-message"></div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>





<div id="totalcost"></div>
```

when we remove div of select fields, it works as i want. but i want it like above example because there are other fields to show also.

```js
$('body').on('change', '#visitorcount', function() {
            for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
                if (i <= $('#visitorcount').val()) {
                    $('#person' + i).show();
                    $('#country' + i).show();
                } else {
                    $('#person' + i).hide();
                    $('#country' + i).hide();
                }
            }
        });
        $('body').on('change', '.ct,#visitorcount', function() {
            var priceforcountry = 0;
            $('.ct').each(function(index, element) {
                if ($(element).parent().css("display") != "none") {
                    priceforcountry += +$('option:selected', this).data('fee');
                }
            });
            $('#totalcost').text(priceforcountry);
            //alert(priceforcountry);
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group" id="person1">
        <div class="col-sm-4 control-label">Citizenship</div>
        <div class="col-sm-8" id="person1">
            <select class="form-control ct" id="country1" name="visitor1">

                <option value="india" data-fee="20">India</option>
                <option value="usa" data-fee="25">USA</option>


            </select>
            <div class="error-message"></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <select id="visitorcount" name="visitorcount">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
    </select>


    <div class="row visitor" id="person2" style="display: none;">

                        <select name="visitor[2][country]" class="form-control ct" id="country2">
                            <option value="india" data-fee="20">India</option>
                            <option value="usa" data-fee="25">USA</option>


                        </select>
                    
                    </div>
  





    <div class="row visitor" id="person3" style="display: none;">
       
                        <select name="person[3][country]" class="form-control ct" id="country3" style="display:none">
                            <option value="india" data-fee="20">India</option>
                            <option value="usa" data-fee="25">USA</option>

                        </select>
                        <div class="error-message"></div>
                    </div>


    
    
    <div class="row visitor" id="person4" style="display: none;">
                        <select name="person[4][country]" class="form-control ct" id="country4" style="display:none">
                            <option value="india" data-fee="20">India</option>
                            <option value="usa" data-fee="25">USA</option>

                        </select>
                        <div class="error-message"></div>
                    </div>

    
    
    <div class="row visitor" id="person5" style="display: none;">
                        <select name="person[5][country]" class="form-control ct" id="country5" style="display:none">
                            <option value="india" data-fee="20">India</option>
                            <option value="usa" data-fee="25">USA</option>

                        </select>
                        <div class="error-message"></div>
                    </div>
               




    <div id="totalcost"></div>
```

whats wrong with the first code snippet. why divs are causing this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of looking for css display, just use `$(element).is(':visible')` like so

```js
$('body').on('change', '#visitorcount', function() {
  var val = $('#country1').val();
  for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
    if (i <= $('#visitorcount').val()) {
      $(`#person${i}`).show();
      //Check to see if this is visible, if not
      //Set the default value and show it.
      if(!$(`#country${i}`).is(':visible')){
        $(`#country${i}`).val(val).show();
      }
    } else {
      $(`#person${i}`).hide();
      $(`#country${i}`).hide();
    }
  }
});
$('body').on('change', '.ct,#visitorcount', function() {
  var priceforcountry = 0;
  $('.ct').each(function(index, element) {
    if ($(element).is(':visible')) {
      priceforcountry += +$('option:selected', this).data('fee');
    }
  });
  $('#totalcost').text(priceforcountry);
  //alert(priceforcountry);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group" id="person1">
  <div class="col-sm-4 control-label">Citizenship</div>
  <div class="col-sm-8" id="person1">
    <select class="form-control ct" id="country1" name="visitor1">

      <option value="india" data-fee="20">India</option>
      <option value="usa" data-fee="25">USA</option>


    </select>
    <div class="error-message"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<select id="visitorcount" name="visitorcount">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
</select>


<div class="row visitor" id="person2" style="display: none;">
  <div class="col-md-7">
    <div class="form-horizontal">
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-4 control-label">Citizenship</div>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
          <select name="visitor[2][country]" class="form-control ct" id="country2">
            <option value="india" data-fee="20">India</option>
            <option value="usa" data-fee="25">USA</option>


          </select>

        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>




<div class="row visitor" id="person3" style="display: none;">
  <div class="col-md-7">
    <div class="form-horizontal">

      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-4 control-label" data-xtr-key="Citizenship">Citizenship</div>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
          <select name="person[3][country]" class="form-control ct" id="country3" style="display:none">
            <option value="india" data-fee="20">India</option>
            <option value="usa" data-fee="25">USA</option>

          </select>
          <div class="error-message"></div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>



<div class="row visitor" id="person4" style="display: none;">
  <div class="col-md-7">
    <div class="form-horizontal">

      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-4 control-label" data-xtr-key="Citizenship">Citizenship</div>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
          <select name="person[4][country]" class="form-control ct" id="country4" style="display:none">
            <option value="india" data-fee="20">India</option>
            <option value="usa" data-fee="25">USA</option>

          </select>
          <div class="error-message"></div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="row visitor" id="person5" style="display: none;">
  <div class="col-md-7">
    <div class="form-horizontal">

      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-4 control-label" data-xtr-key="Citizenship">Citizenship</div>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
          <select name="person[4][country]" class="form-control ct" id="country5" style="display:none">
            <option value="india" data-fee="20">India</option>
            <option value="usa" data-fee="25">USA</option>

          </select>
          <div class="error-message"></div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>





<div id="totalcost"></div>
```

Comment: one more question i have if you can help is, what i want is, if i select a option in first select box and when i click on number of visitor, then other select boxes should have same option selected by default.

Comment: I updated my example to do what you asked, if an item is not visible, it will show it and set the value to the same as the first one. Visible items will stay the same